# phant : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: django, node.js

i am trying to get json data  from phant to a django application but everytime I am getting the following error :

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have tried adding 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to both node.js for phant and django but unable to get the data.

Comment: used this http://phant.io/graphing/google/2014/07/07/graphing-data/ to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requesting data from phant app to django app. You need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on django app.

Posting how you are adding 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to Django app will be helpful to answer.

You may consider using [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers). Check the configuration options carefully.